# UITableView get the value of the section while scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (NSString*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%i",section);
}
```

If I scroll down the table I get the value of
0
2
3
4 ...
If up
0
2
3
4
2
1 ...
How to get the value without reduction or increase by 2?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is a delegate method you can implement to supply the titles for the sections. The table view will then call this method repeatedly at its own discretion, as sections are scrolled onto the screen, to ask you for the title it should display. You really shouldn't bother about the order or number of calls that method gets. Just return the correct title.

Comment: I need to change the value on the value of the name UILabel section if it is higher Navigation Bar

Comment: I don't understand. What is higher? What name? What UILabel?

Comment: If i do like this _myTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[monthArray objectAtIndex:section-2]]; Then you scroll down all the true test runs, but when you scroll up there.

Comment: can you explain us what do you need? We will help you.

Comment: If the section name above Navigation Bar I need to get the index of this section

Comment: It would really help if you could tell your end goal. Do you want to display some information in the navigation bar depending on where the user currently scrolled in the table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView will call tableView:titleForHeaderInSection at its own discretion in order to get the title for a particular section when it needs it. It makes no promises about the order in which it will request the titles.

This should make no difference; it is up to *you* to know the title for a given section number regardless of the order, and return it from that delegate method when the table view asks for it. Try to read up on how UITableViews and their delegate/data source work together, and I bet you'll find that the thing you are trying to do is really easy.

EDIT: Now that you have clarified your goal slightly, I would suggest looking at the -indexPathsForVisibleRows method in UITableView. This will give you the NSIndexPaths that are currently visible in the table view, and you can find the index path with the smallest section value to determine the first section that is still visible/invisible in the table.

Answer (score 0):

That method should just return the title for a specific section, regardless the order of the section index values.

The tableview will manage the section headers by itself, and just asks the datasource when it needs info. The datasource should know how to map the section index with the desired title.